# In the Hunt for Kaprekar's Constants for more than 4 digits.

Tags: number-theory, constants

[Kaprekar's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_%28number%29) is $6174$ . Take any four digit number with at least two different digits; create two four digit numbers by writing the digits in descending order and in ascending order; subtract the two numbers, and repeat.  Eventually, you will end up at 6174, where the process stays.

I have been trying to find a similar constant for 5 digits but am only getting these 3 series .
$$1) 74943 ->  62964 -> 71973 -> 83952 -> repeats $$
$$ 2) 63954 -> 61974 -> 82962 -> 75933 -> repeats$$
$$ 3)  53955 -> 59994 -> repeats$$

Similarly a series for 6 digits 
$$   851742 -> 750843 -> 840852 -> 860832 -> 862632 -> 642654 -> 420876 -> repeat$$
**I would like to know is there any way to generate these kinds of numbers or series for n digit number?**

Comment: Probably relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaprekarRoutine.html

Comment: $(\chi^4(q) - \chi^4(-q)) / (8 q) = 1 /(\chi^4(q^2)\chi^6(-q^2))$

Comment: I don't want to hijack the question, but is this somehow related to the Collatz conjecture?